# Error when building Next.js 13.4 app: Type 'ResolvingMetadata | undefined' does not satisfy the constraint 'ResolvingMetadata'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13, app-router

I'm trying to dynamically generate metadata for my Next.js 13.4 app using the following code:

```
export async function generateMetadata(
    { params, searchParams }: Props,
) {
    try {
        // read route params
        const id = params.itemId;

        // fetch data
        const product = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/catelog/item/find/${id}`, {cache: 'no-store'}).then((res) => res.json());

        return {
            title: `Example | ${product.product_name}`,
            description: product.product_description ?? `best selling items at Example store`,
            openGraph: {
                images: [product.product_image],
                title: `Example | ${product.product_name}`,
                description: product.product_description ?? `best selling items at Example store`,
                type: "website"
            },
        };
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            title: `Example | Not found`,
            description: `Product not found`,
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine in development, but I'm encountering an error when trying to build the app. The error message is:

```
Type error: Type 'ResolvingMetadata | undefined' does not satisfy the constraint 'ResolvingMetadata'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ResolvedMetadata>'.
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this error. Can someone please help me understand the root cause of this issue and provide guidance on how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: @jacob still getting the same error with npm run build,

Type error: Type 'ResolvingMetadata | undefined' does not satisfy the constraint 'ResolvingMetadata'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ResolvedMetadata>'.

  28 | if ('generateMetadata' in entry) {
  29 |   checkFields<Diff<PageProps, FirstArg<MaybeField<TEntry, 'generateMetadata'>>, 'generateMetadata'>>()
> 30 |   checkFields<Diff<ResolvingMetadata, SecondArg<MaybeField<TEntry, 'generateMetadata'>>, 'generateMetadata'>>()
     |                                       ^
  31 | }

Comment: Could you give a sample code project can produce your error by any share code platform?

Answer (score 0):

Build error goes away when you replace it with below snippet.

```
export async function generateMetadata(): Promise<Metadata>
```